# How would I make a website change depending on what device it is viewed on?

Tags: html, device

My website information on Asia, the home page has buttons for each country. It works fine on computers, Laptops, large iPads or Tablets and other large screens. But on smaller screens such as Phones and smaller iPads and Tablets, the buttons are too small to read and tap on the right one. What more text is harder to read on the smaller tablets.

Is there some sort tag that allows the content to change depending on the device?

If you want to view the the website the URL is: http://asianindex.byethost24.com

(Try viewing on both small and big screens)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tzsubn8g/) for you so that you can have a live preview of what the code below is doing. Make sure that you move the preview window with your mouse so that you can simulate the width of a big screen and of a small one.

What I am doing is that I am telling my option `divs` to display differently when the screen has `max-width: 575px` and when the max width is higher, they act normally (no condition).

> You can read more about that on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
  #main>div {
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

div>div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div> option 1 </div>
  <div> option 2 </div>
  <div> option 3 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I am not the best, and there might be far more better solutions, but for me: 
I just change the Html contents in javascript:
for example:
I use this for my top content bar, where if the device is small enough: say:"document.body.clientWidth>=750" or device width is less than 750px, then I change the top bar.
Before you start: remember that to include multiple lines of string, you need the "`" sign which is above tab(next to numberkey 1) not the normal quotes sign.

```js
function homebtn(){
  if (window.location.href.split('/').pop() === ""||Number(window.location.href.split('#').pop())>0) { 
    sendDataToLoad(jdata_location,jdata_imageurl,16,one,one,jdata_level);
      return '<a onclick="modeUPLOAD();"id= uploadbtn>Upload</a>'
}
  else{
    return '<a href="./">Home</a>'
  }
}


function loadheader(){
  if(document.body.clientWidth>=750){ 
    document.getElementById('topbar').innerHTML=`
    <p> <a href="/">MosaicTokyo </a> </p>
    <ul>
              <li><a href="./contact">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a href="./login">Log-In</a></li>
              <li>${homebtn()}</li>


    </ul>
  `

}else{
    document.getElementById('topbar').innerHTML=`<p> <a href="/">MosaicTokyo</a> </p>             
    <div class="dropdown"> //I made a dropdown menu instead of buttons next to each other
    <button class="dropbtn"><img src="/images/three-bars-icon-5.jpg" alt=""></button>
       <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="./contact">Contact</a>
   <a href="./login">LogIn</a>                     
   ${homebtn()}
     </div>`

}
```

This is my top bar for HTML

```html
<nav id="topbar"></nav>
```

This script is also how I make the top content bar of multiple pages the same without copy and paste.

TLDR: Use script to change the layout of the Page and if you assigned elements a different id, you can just manipulate that element in CSS without messing with your tablet view!
also can you change the buttons style?

Comment: I`ll try that and yes i am going to do that soon